# Azure Pipeline - Exclude pipeline trigger for every pull request build validation

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have two yaml files; one is for the CI.yml pipeline, and another is for the CD.yml pipeline

The current setup is for every successful CI.yml build; the CD.yml will trigger afterwards.

This is the code/config of my CD.yml:

```
 trigger: none
 resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: CI
      source: "CI"
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - main
          exclude:
            - '*' 
          stages:
            - 'Package: CI'
```

I need to set up a pull request build validation for CI.yml main branch. The issue is whenever there is a pull request, and the CI.yml completes its build validation pull request. It also triggers the CD.yml, which I don't want, is there any other way to exclude the PR in the CD trigger? It seems that the 'pr' is an unknown property under 'pipelines:' and the stage filter is not working since I already set that if the build_reason = pull request, the 'Package: CI' will be skipped. The exclusion of all branches ('*') also doesn't work.

Comment: can you share your CI yaml?

Answer (score 0):

If wanting to keep your pipelines separated then one approach would be to set the trigger for the CI pipeline to none and have it triggered via the [build validation on branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation) in ADO.

This would then be triggered anytime someone is merging into the main branch. Remove the pipeline dependency on the CD pipeline set the trigger to the main branch. The workflow then would be CI triggered as a build validation anytime there is a request to merge into main and CD to run after the merge into main.

An alternative that I would actually recommend is to leverage one .yml pipeline file for both the CI and the CD.

This would look something like:
stages:

```
- template: stages/adf_build_stage.yml@templates
  parameters:
    serviceName: ${{ parameters.serviceName }}
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')}}:
  - template: stages/adf_deploy_stage.yml@templates
    parameters:
      environmentObjects: ${{ parameters.environmentObjects }}
      serviceName: ${{ parameters.serviceName }}
```

The [azure devops expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) can have other criteria. The jist of this is the same steps you are executiong for your CI should be the first steps of your CD. (i.e. build, code scanning, publishing the artifact) so why not combine them and conditionally run the deployment. This will lead to a reduction in maintaining multiple pipelines. Just ensure you have something in place to consider pipeline retention since the same pipeline will be used for CI and deployments.

Comment: I already tried removing "include main branch" and excluding "all" branches but it still triggers the CD pipeline for every build validation pull request even though I didn't complete the merge. Is there a way to exclude the trigger from every Pull request?

Comment: Remove the CI pipeline resource.

Comment: I can't, I also want the CD to trigger if the CI was successfully built except only if the CI build is triggered due to pull request build validation.

Comment: Wouldn't you want the PR to be approved first? The CI will trigger as part of the build validation against the branch. The CD will run as the trigger when code is merged into the branch.